# Process Azure ServiceBus messages in multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, azureservicebus

I am using Azure ServiceBus topics in my .Net Core 3.1 application to process messages. Because we've multiple tenants I want to use concurrent processing of the messages in multiple threads.
Currently I've the following method to process the messages:

```
 private async Task CheckAndSubscribeToTopicsAsync<T>(string topicName, string subscriptionName)
 {
     var subscriptionExists = await _queueAdmin.SubscriptionExistsAsync(topicName, subscriptionName);
     if (subscriptionExists)
     {
         await _messageSubscriber.SusbcribeTopicMessageAsync<T>(topicName, subscriptionName, ProcessAlertAsync);
     }
 }

  public async Task SusbcribeTopicMessageAsync<T>(string topicName, string subscriptionName, Func<T, string, MessageType, Task<bool>> callback)
  {
      var processor = this.CreateProcessor(topicName, subscriptionName, ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock);
      processor.ProcessMessageAsync += async (args) =>
      {
          await MessageHandler<T>(args, topicName, callback);
      };
      processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
      await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
  }
```

This works fine but I want to use multiple tasks to process the messages.
Something like the following:

```
private async Task CheckAndSubscribeToTopicsAsync<T>(string topicName, string subscriptionName, int numberOfThreads)
    {
        var subscriptionExists = await _queueAdmin.SubscriptionExistsAsync(topicName, subscriptionName);
        if (subscriptionExists)
        {
            var subscriptionTasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
            {
                subscriptionTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await _messageSubscriber.SusbcribeTopicMessageAsync<T>(topicName, subscriptionName, ProcessAlertAsync);
                }));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(subscriptionTasks);
        }
    }
```

My question here is whether it's a good idea to do this considering we have a single VM to handle multiple projects. However, I was thinking of using a very small number of threads, for example, 5. Also I want to know if my approach is fine or is there a better way?

Comment: I'd advise against starting more than one processor for a single entity.  Each processor will launch 2 persistent background tasks, one that manages processor health, the other that reads/delivers messages.  You'll be doing more work than you need to and stressing your resources.  The answer for akg179 below is the recommendation for managing concurrency. Also, please be aware that .NET Core 3.1 reached end of life and is no longer a platform that the Azure SDK officially supports.  While we won't intentionally break you, there are no guarantees that new package versions will continue to work.

Answer (score 2):

The `ServiceBusProcessor` has a constructor [CreateProcessor(String, String, ServiceBusProcessorOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient.createprocessor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusclient-createprocessor(system-string-system-string-azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusprocessoroptions)) that allows you to pass `ServiceBusProcessorOptions` instance.

The `ServiceBusProcessorOptions` class has a property called [MaxConcurrentCalls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusprocessoroptions.maxconcurrentcalls?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusprocessoroptions-maxconcurrentcalls) which can be used to get/set the maximum number of concurrent calls to the message handler the processor should initiate.

You can find an example of an asynchronous receive operation that uses `MaxConcurrentCalls` in [this MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#concurrent-operations)

Answer (score 1):

Manually creating multiple tasks to run separate message processors for the same Service Bus subscription can lead to unnecessary complexity, potential message handling issues, and inefficient resource use. you could use the built-in `MaxConcurrentCalls` setting of the `ServiceBusProcessorOptions` to configure the desired level of concurrent message processing within a single `ServiceBusProcessor`. This allows the Service Bus library to manage concurrency efficiently without manually creating multiple tasks.

Here is the code you could try:

```
public async Task SubscribeTopicMessageAsync<T>(string topicName, string subscriptionName, Func<T, string, MessageType, Task<bool>> callback, int maxConcurrentCalls)
{
    var options = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
    {
        MaxConcurrentCalls = maxConcurrentCalls, 
        AutoCompleteMessages = false,
        ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock
    };

    var processor = this.CreateProcessor(topicName, subscriptionName, options);
    processor.ProcessMessageAsync += async (args) =>
    {
        await MessageHandler<T>(args, topicName, callback);
    };
    processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
    await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
}
```